# call nonstatic methods from java to cpp using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to call non static method from java to C++ using JNI
My Java Code is here:

```
public class hellojava
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
     System.out.println("This is the main function from the HelloWorld java class.");
  }

public void message()
{
    System.out.println("call from object");

}
```

}

And my C++ code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>


JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options;

options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/../nonstaticJavaMethods/";     
//Path to the java source code

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = &options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;


int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
if(ret < 0)
    printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");     
return env;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVM * jvm;
env = create_vm(&jvm);
if (env == NULL)
    return 1;   


//jclass clsH=NULL;
jmethodID midMain = NULL;
jstring square;
jclass clsH = env->FindClass("helloWorld");
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "<init>", "void(V)");
jobject object = env->NewObject(clsH, constructor);



//Obtaining Method IDs
if (clsH != NULL)
{          midMain = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "message", "void(V)");
           env->CallVoidMethod(clsH, midMain, object,NULL); 
}
else
{
    printf("\nUnable to find the requested class\n");       
}




//Release resources.
int n = jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
return 0;

}

My code compiles but it is giving me runtime error. Following is the error
```

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdf3f5126bb, pid=11302, tid=140596827092800

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c46bb]  alloc_object(_jclass*, Thread*)+0x1b

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping,    
 try    
 "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved    as  

 /home/../nonstaticJavaMethods/hs_err_pid11302.log      
 Aborted!
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to [immibis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis) answer, i also think the call

```
jclass clsH = env->FindClass("helloWorld");
```

isn't returning anything, as your class is called

```
public class hellojava
```

So your application is probably seg-faulting in `GetMethodID()` or `NewObject()`

Answer (score 1):

`void(V)` is not a valid method descriptor.

Because there is no method called `<init>` with the descriptor `void(V)` (which there can't be, because it's invalid), `GetMethodID` returns 0. Then you try to create a new object using this invalid method ID.

The method descriptor for a method that takes no arguments and returns `void` (which a constructor is) is `()V`.

Comment: `javap -classpath /home/../nonstaticJavaMethods/ -s -public hellojava | egrep -A 2 "<init>"`

Comment: @TomBlodget there is no method called `<init>` *with the descriptor `void(V)`*.

Comment: Oh, right, not quite as straightforward for constructors. Anyway, query by class name but use "<init>" in JNI. Here's a better example: `javap -s -public java.lang.String | egrep -A 2 "String\("`

Comment: @TomBlodget constructors are the same as other methods except the name is always `<init>` and the return type is always `V` (corresponding to `void` in Java). `void(V)` is not a valid descriptor for any method - it should be `()V` for a method that takes no parameters and returns `void`.